# Go tests debugging

Tags: debugging, testing, go, ide, intellij-15

Is there a way to debug tests in Go using an IDE like IntelliJ ? I am using the Go plugin for intelliJ and seems like when providing a debug configuration, the debug button is disabled.

Comment: I've had success using LiteIDE to do this though it gets fairly wonky sometimes. https://github.com/visualfc/liteide

Comment: I did try that but found IntelliJ more convenient and thus exploring a way to debug the tests here. LiteIDE is definitely one option. Thanks.

Comment: The IntelliJ plugin uses Delve as a debugging backend whereas LiteIDE uses GDB. GDB has poor support for Go that's why it produces a bad results. On the other side, Delve is not yet mature and will still have issues of its own. I find Delve to be more stable in general however.

Answer (score 4):

It is **possible in Gogland: 1.0 Preview, Build EAP 12, 172.3757.46**.

This version has an expiration date: November 9, 2017, but there are already [newer versions released](https://www.jetbrains.com/go/download/#section=linux) and they probably have later expiration dates.

Answer (score 3):

Currently it's not possible to debug tests, please watch over [this issue](https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin/issues/1855) to see when this will be supported.