# How to avoid duplicate tests in Go?

Tags: unit-testing, debugging, testing, go, code-duplication

Since Go [does not allow to debug tests in some IDEs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34889319/go-tests-debugging) (see also this [issue](https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin/issues/1855)) I had to write my tests twice in my [queue implementation](https://github.com/drylib/drylib/tree/master/go/src/queue).

One time inside [main.go](https://github.com/drylib/drylib/blob/master/go/src/queue/main/main.go), second time - inside [queue_test.go](https://github.com/drylib/drylib/blob/master/go/src/queue/test/queue_test.go)

I use Visual Studio Code with delve.

What is the best IDE or pattern to debug Go tests without duplicating them ?

Comment: Please provide sme runnable examples.

Comment: "Go does not allow to debug tests" is a very bold statement of which I think it is totally false. How come you think this is true?

Comment: @Volker - I think he posted a link about why he _thinks_ this is true.

Comment: @jangroth And I think Java cannot be debugged at all because XEDIT cannot do it. We live in a strange world...

Comment: I use VS Code with delve.

Comment: I assumed that if there are at least 2 major IDEs that cannot debug (Visual Studio Code and IntelliJ) then it's not possible to debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your IDE is unable to debug tests.

Try something different. For example, as of today, the early access edition of [Gogland](https://www.jetbrains.com/go/) works quite well with regards to debugging, even with tests. It uses the [Delve](https://github.com/derekparker/delve) debugger under the hood, so you can even resort to [run the debugger](https://github.com/derekparker/delve/tree/master/Documentation) manually from terminal or check to see if it is already [integrated](https://github.com/derekparker/delve/blob/master/Documentation/EditorIntegration.md) with your IDE of choice.